# Pass variable to Ipython Widget

Tags: python, input, widget, ipython

I have a simple widget that modifies a plot, here is the definition:

```
#Plot function
def plf(x,lm,ls):
    plt.plot(x[lm:ls],np.sin(x)[lm:ls])
```

this function takes a list `x` an plot `sin(x)`, `lm` and `ls` controls the number of data that is ploted, the problem is when i try to plot a determinated list of data, for example

```
list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

and if i try

```
interact(plf,x=list,lm=(0,max(x)//2,1),ls=(max(x)//2,max(x),1))
```

throws me the error:

```
NameError: name 'x' is not defined
```

so, how can i define `x` so it can be any list that i want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you are trying to do?

```
%matplotlib inline
from IPython.html.widgets import interact, fixed
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def plf(x,lm,ls):
    plt.plot(x[lm:ls],np.sin(x)[lm:ls])

data = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
max_lm = max(data)//2
max_ls = max(data)

interact(plf,x=fixed(data),lm=(0,max_lm,1),ls=(max_lm, max_ls,1))
```

Comment: Ohhh thaks, this is exactly what i wanted